# Power BI DAX calculated column to find alternatives from a different table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following datasets:

1. "Compare Data" table:

[image]

2. "Full Data" table

[image]

I'm looking to create a calculated column where I can later show and count who and how many alternative vendors to A and their Average Costs if "Model" and "Group" columns are used as slicers.

Ex:

If W5 is chosen from the "Model" slicer AND/OR EEC is selected from the "Group" slicer,

•  Alternatives to A = B & E & R **[Ignore A in the results]**

•  Number of Alternatives = 3

•  Average Cost:

A = (100 + 150 + 105 +3000 +1215)/5 = 914

B = 85/1 = 85

E = 1115/1 = 1115

R = 450/1 = 450

I don't know if it should be a calculated column or a measure because I'd like to put these information in a Bubble Chart later where it shows A's Average Cost and its alternatives' costs with regard to "Model" and "Group" slicers.

Please if you have any solutions, can you show me how to get this done? Thank you so much!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @StelioK Hi, somebody helped me out with this measure but it's not quite what I want since it doesn't work out with Bubble Chart. Here it is: Measure =
VAR mymodel =
    VALUES ( 'Compare Data'[Model] )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX (
        EXCEPT (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                VALUES ( 'Full Data'[Vendor Name] ),
                'Full Data'[Engine Model] IN mymodel
            ),
            VALUES ( 'Compare Data'[Name] )
        ),
        [Vendor Name],
        ", "
    )